# Pinch to zoom in IDA Pro

Tags: ida

I have a touchscreen Windows 8 tablet and I would like to be able to use this platform to easily browse control flow graphs in IDA Pro and display them to other people. There are a couple of problems I keep running into - but the earliest problem I ran into is that my tablet has no scroll wheel capability and no keypad with +/- on it, so I cannot zoom in and out of graphs. This is not necessarily a reverse-engineering question per se, but is it easily possible to enable zoom functionality on this platform in a way that I have not thought of yet? What would an extension to IDA that enables pinch-to-zoom require?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the program GestureKey would allow you to map gestures to keyboard or mouse actions, for use with IDA Pro:

[image: GestureKey]

There's a nice demo video of using GestureKey to allow pinch-to-zoom to work with Google Earth: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_EoXY3Jhrw

Unfortunately, [the developers of GestureKey have abandoned it](http://gestureworks.com/gesturekey), but it looks like you still might be able to get it [from here](http://www.mageca.com/app_info?app_pk=50).

You may also want to post your question in a more generic form to the [Software Recommendations StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).